# NSData and NSArray -[__NSArrayM length]

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, nsarray, nsdata

I don't know what's going here but this piece of code is throwing exceptions. Basically Im storing NSData into an array then retrieve it to use inside the UIImageView. here's the code.

```
    imagesDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *imgDataArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:imageDataArray];
    for(int i = 0; i < [imgDataArr count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[imgDataArr objectAtIndex:i]);
        UIImage *thumbImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [imgDataArr objectAtIndex:i]]; //this throws the exception
        [imagesDataArray addObject:thumbImage];
        [thumbImage release];
    }
    [imgDataArr release];
```

as you can see, the same code [imgDataArr objectAtIndex:i] I used in NSLog and it's working fine but when I pair it up with initWithData it goes freaky. here's the error log.

```
    2011-10-17 15:56:47.008 myapp[39498:b303] -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized   
    selector sent to instance 0x4c98420
    2011-10-17 15:56:47.009 myapp[39498:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaug
```

Comment: Then i would guess something goes wrong inside `initWithData`. Can you provide a backtrace?

Comment: Please edit the question and post the code you’re using to insert objects into `imageDataArray`. Also, is `imageDataArray` an automatic variable? An instance variable? How do you create it?

Comment: where u assign data imgDataArr

Comment: well, It turned out to be a problem with inserting arrays of NSData. Sorry guys, got it fixed already. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

check you array name .imagesDataArray

```
imagesDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.jpg",@"image4.png",@"image6.png",@"image7.png",nil];
NSArray *imgDataArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:imagesDataArray];
for(int i = 0; i < [imgDataArr count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[imgDataArr objectAtIndex:i]);
    UIImage *thumbImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [imgDataArr objectAtIndex:i]]; //this throws the exception
    [imagesDataArray addObject:thumbImage];
    [thumbImage release];
}
[imgDataArr release];
```

Comment: In your answer both `imagesDataArray` and `imgDataArr` have no elements, which means that the program would never enter that loop.

Comment: Your edit still doesn’t work: you’re inserting strings into the array instead of `NSData` objects.